# replace div if text box not active jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm not sure how to check whether or not the box has a cursor in it. I want to replace a div if the text box is empty or isn't active.

.js.erb file

```
if($('#headersearch').val().trim() ==  "") {
  $("#header_user_list").html('');}
else if(!$('#headersearch').is(":focus")){          <-- this line isnt working
  $("#header_user_list").html('');}
else{$("#header_user_list").html('<%= j render @header_users %>')}
```

Comment: seems to be working http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2TtaZ/1/

Comment: strange im not sure why this isn't working im using 2.0.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `focusout` - [documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/).

Comment: I tried this $('#headersearch').focusout().$("#header_user_list").html(''); no luck tho

Comment: Look at the documentation for the correct syntax:

$('#headersearch').focusout(function() {
  $('#header_user_list").html('');
});

Answer (score 1):

Here i have coded some lines, may be this is what you are looking for

```
$('#headersearch').focusout(function(){
$("#header_user_list").html('focusout');
});          


$('#headersearch').focusin(function(){
 $("#header_user_list").html('focusin');
})
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k6S3m/7/)